# Plotting a function using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have updated the working example.
I would like to plot the function sM0[s] in the system below. I use the same expression as the first parametric plot which works properly.
I dont want to type the expression of sM0[s] manually as this is a simplified example. The original problem is more complicated.
Thank you

```
q0 = 5.3;
ε0 = 2.2;
Γ = 5/3;
μ = 0.001;
ψ0 = 40;
l = μ/2;
Ω0 = 10.112;

ω0[s_] := ( l R[s] μ)/((l^2 + R[s]^2)^2)  
h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]* μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)] 
U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)

sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
Dsonic[s_] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1) +
h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3)  
dΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + 
Δ0[s]^Γ) ε0^2 (-2 R[s]^2 + (l^2 + R[s]^2) F[s]) Δ0[s]^(2 Γ)


dF[s_] := F[s]*Dsonic[s] + (F[s]^2 (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s]))/(
4 π R[s]^2 sG[s]^2)*Dsonic[s]


Rinit = 0.05;
ξinit = 1.8;
Δinit = ((ξinit - 1)/q0)^(1/(1 - Γ));
Finit = 0.2;
bmin = 0.2;
bmax = 2;
bstep = 0.3;
smax = -2000.;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], 
R'[s] == Dsonic[s],  F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, {b1}];

ParametricPlot[
Evaluate@Table[{R[b1][s], b1*Δ0[b1][s]} /. sol, {b1, bmin, bmax, 
bstep}], {s, 0, smax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {"R", "F"}]

ParametricPlot[
Evaluate@Table[{R[b1][s], sM0[b1][s]} /. sol, {b1, bmin, bmax, 
bstep}], {s, 0, smax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {"R", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(M0\), \(2\)]\)"}]
```

Comment: As stated in the error messages, you have six dependent variables of `s`, i.e., `{F, dF, \[CapitalDelta]0, d\[CapitalDelta]0, Dsonic, R}` and only three equations. The system is underdetermined.

Comment: Also, you define `g0` with a single argument `g0[s_] := ... `; however, in the plot you try using it with an additional argument `g0[b1][s]`

Comment: Thank Bob but the system works. Αll the variables are well defined.  I haven't included the all  functions because are a bit lengthy. b1 is not an argument is a parameter. According to mathematica's help this is the way to write it. As far as i understand.

Comment: Then reduce your problem to a minimal working example that exhibits the issue and for which you can provide all of the code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to post a script?

Comment: You put code (InputForm) in code blocks just like you did above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

q0 = 5.3;
ε0 = 2.2;
Γ = 5/3;
μ = 0.001;
ψ0 = 40;
l = μ/2;
Ω0 = 10.112;

ω0[s_] := (l R[s] μ)/((l^2 + R[s]^2)^2)
h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]*μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)]
U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - 
      h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)

sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
Dsonic[s_] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + \
Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0[
         s]^(1 - Γ) + 1) + 
   h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3)
dΔ0[
  s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + Δ0[
      s]^Γ) ε0^2 (-2 R[s]^2 + (l^2 + R[s]^2) F[
      s]) Δ0[s]^(2 Γ)

dF[s_] := 
 F[s]*Dsonic[s] + (F[s]^2 (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s]))/(4 π R[s]^2 sG[s]^2)*
   Dsonic[s]

Rinit = 0.05;
ξinit = 1.8;
Δinit = ((ξinit - 1)/q0)^(1/(1 - Γ));
Finit = 0.2;
bmin = 0.2;
bmax = 2;
bstep = 0.3;
smax = -2000.;
```

Solving,

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == 
     dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], R'[s] == Dsonic[s], 
    F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
    R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, {b1}];
```

Plotting,

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[{R[b1][s], b1*Δ0[b1][s]} /. sol,
   {b1, bmax, bmin, -bstep}],
 {s, 0, smax},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"R", "F"},
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[Range[bmax, bmin, -bstep],
   LegendLabel -> Style["b1", 14]],
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Although `sM0` is defined with a single argument, it evaluates in terms of `Δ0` which needs a parameter to match the [`ParametricFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction.html)

```
sM0[s]

(* 5.3 Δ0[s]^(1/3) + Δ0[s] *)
```

Consequently, use

```
sM0[s] /. Δ0 :> Δ0[b1]

(* 5.3 Δ0[b1][s]^(1/3) + Δ0[b1][s] *)
```

For a given value of `s`, `sM0` does not vary with `b1`

```
Table[
 Table[{R[b1][s], sM0[s] /. Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b1][s]} /. sol,
   {b1, bmin, bmax, bstep}] // Union,
 {s, 0, smax, smax/4}]

(* {{{0.05, 30.6938}}, {{0.0500331, 28.7783}}, {{0.0500331, 
   28.7783}}, {{0.0500331, 28.7783}}, {{0.0500331, 28.7783}}} *)
```

Plotting only with `bmin` and `bmax` to see that the plots coincide:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[{R[b1][s], sM0[s] /. Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b1][s]} /. sol,
   {b1, bmax, bmin, -bmax + bmin}],
 {s, 0, smax},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  {"R", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(M0\), \(2\)]\)"},
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[{bmax, bmin},
   LegendLabel -> Style["b1", 14]],
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bob